# Design a database table using this data

Tags: sql, database, database-design, datatable, normalization

Hi I just want to sort out these fields to a table. But I'm having trouble.

I have details of cities.

These are main city detail examples.

```
CityName CityID 
Colombo   001
Kandy     002
```

Kandy is Directly connected to these cities

```
 CityName    CityID DistancefromKandy
 Katugastota 006    1km 
 Peadeniya   008    2km
```

I want to store distance between **every** city. As an example Katugastota to Peradeniya, Colombo to Katugastota, Colombo to Kandy and Kandy To Peradeniya too.
And for a singe city I want to store what are the directly connected cities and the distance to those cities. 
How to sort this data to tables..?Any ideas.. I have given the table structure I tried but I cant add the distance between each city in to that and the directly connected cities and distance to directly connected cities in this..
Appreciate any help in this..
I just don't need the sql, if someone can suggest a better table design that would be a great help.

Comment: why not store the geocordinates (Lat/Lang) and work out the distance?

Comment: @EvilEpidemic the application is simple depend on raw data. No way of including coordinates and calculating distance.

Answer (score 1):

Like *@EvilEpidemic* suggested above, my first choice would be to store coordinates (latitude & longitude) for each city and calculate the distances between them.

That said, if you need to store your pre-calculated distances for specific pairs of cities, then you may want to try the following:

Add a table that includes two (2) CityID columns (for example, `SourceCityId` and `DestinationCityId`) as well as a NOT NULL distance column (of a numeric data type).

For example, in SQL Server you might have a table like (this oversimplified example assumes you store distances as `int` kilometers, but feel free to change the data type as needed):

```
CREATE TABLE Distances (
    [SourceCityId] NOT NULL int,
    [DestinationCityId] NOT NULL int,
    [DistanceInKilometers] NOT NULL int,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Distances] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [SourceCityId] ASC,
        [DestinationCityId] ASC
    )
)
```

Comment: How to store directly connecting cities?

Comment: The `Distances` table (outlined above) includes the primary keys for two directly connected cities (i.e., `SourceCityId` and `DestinationCityId`) as well as the distance between them. So, for example, the table row showing the connection between Kandy and Katugastota would appear in the table as: `SourceCityId`=002, `DestinationCityId`=006, & `DistanceInKilometers`=1.

Comment: +1, but a small nitpick: `SourceCityId` and `DestinationCityId` should reference (via foreign keys) the city table - which you probably already know but forgot to spell-out in the answer.

Comment: Also, the database should "defend" itself from the same pair being represented twice. For example, if {Colombo, Kandy, 100km} is present, the database should **not** allow: {Kandy, Colombo, 101km}. Also, {Colombo, Colombo, ...} should not be allowed (we know it's always 0km). This can be achieved via a simple: `CHECK (SourceCityId < DestinationCityId)`.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Yes, of course, I agree completely. To make this work, foreign keys and other ways to protect against duplication are required. However, without knowing all of the specifics of the original poster's db schema, I left that for the original poster to work out.